# Inside glass not the same color as the exterior glass

Tags: mesh, node-editor

Is there a way to make the glass on the inside of my interior the same color as the glass on the outside? They are the same mesh but for some reason they are both different colors. The glass is blue when outside but see through when inside.
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your glass node has white color so any color you see is coming from the Glossy node that has blueish tint and your sky. If you want realistic glass, you only need the glass node. Glass and Glossy materials are going to reflect the light and color of the environment. If you want a surface that is the same color regardless of the environment (not realistic) use Transparent and Diffuse nodes instead.

Comment: I removed the glossy node but the color still is not the same inside.

Comment: You are probably still using glass node which also has glossy aspect that reflects light. Use transparent.